# Can't add a new component to my angular 2 app with typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, atom-editor, angular-components

I'm using Angular 2 CLI and I created the component "MyComponent" with the `ng generate component MyComponent`. As far as I know I have to add the component to the directive key-value-pair of the `@Component` decorator, but the typescript compilation fails at this point, saying that:

```
ERROR in [default] /Users/Philip/Desktop/Angular2/src/app/app.component.ts:8:2 
Argument of type '{ selector: string; template: any; styles: any[]; directives: typeof MyComponentComponent[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Component'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'directives' does not exist in type 'Component'.
```

This is my code for the app:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MyComponentComponent } from './my-component/my-component.component'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  directives: [MyComponentComponent],
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';
}
```

I didn't touch the code of the generated component, but just in case:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component.component.css']
})

export class MyComponentComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: which version are you using of angular2?

Comment: Are you using a version of the CLI that matches the angular version you're using? `directives` at the component level was deprecated then removed (in RC6, IIRC).

Comment: I installed both today using the npm command as shown in the documentation. Both should be up to date, I don't know if they match though.

Comment: Did you use `angular-cli@webpack`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Error itself says that **directives doesn't exist in** **Component** as it has been deprecated. try this code shown below,

```
import { MyComponentComponent } from './my-component/my-component.component'
import {CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA} from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
   ...
   ...
   declarations:[AppComponent,MyComponentComponent], //<---need to declare 
   schemas:     [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]             //<---added this line
})
```

And remove **directives:[MyComponentComponent]** from **AppComponent**.

Comment: Thank you. I already got this declared in my app.module.ts as shown in your post automatically by CLI. The typescript compiles but it doesn't run in the browser. It's a huge error, I've updated it to my original post.

Comment: Then have you removed `directives:[...]` part from `@Component`???? just remove it. I hope it will start working...

Comment: I'm not sure but I just updated my answer with schemas. Check now if it works.

Comment: What was the issue?

Comment: Your fix worked even before, I just messed up some of my spelling when including the component.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Oh great to know it. Enjoy now.

Comment: I don't get why did angular2 changed the earlier method?
Any specific reasons to do so...

Comment: Yes the way you bootstrap app is changed. Everything is module now. There are many changes done to make  app moduler.

Comment: @amirhossein you need to import it like `import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';`

Answer (score 34):

Angular2 Component decorator no longer use these for embedding other components. We will need to use a new meta data called entryComponents instead. See below as an example ...

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  entryComponents:[VehicleListComponent]
})
```

The vehicle-list-component has the following component metadata..

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-vehicle-list',
  templateUrl: './vehicle-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./vehicle-list.component.css'],
  providers: [VehicleService]
})
```

Comment: I just replaced "directives" with "entryComponents" and got it to work. 
Read more here:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Component-decorator.html

Comment: Same issue here, this answer is helpful. Can someone explain why the name change?

Comment: I also make reference on @@NgModule putting the component on declarations key and import it on the top of the file (in my case @@NgModule is on app.module.ts).

Answer (score 1):

if you use Angular CLI then the new component will be automatically imported and added to declarations section of @ngmodule in app.module.ts . We don't need to write any code for that.

Answer (score 1):

NO NEED TO DO ANYTHING WITH ANGULAR 4 or greater after running the create component command. The error is most likely just you not using the right selector name from the new component metadata file (eg componentname.component.ts).

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1: Use entryComponents tag inside Component

2: Use Angular CLI which automatically imports it, so we don't need to explicitly write code for it.